# Onclick function related to an element dynamically created

Tags: javascript

I have a button that, when clicked, calls a function show().

This function dynamically creates a DIV with a close button!

This close button should call a function to remove the created DIV from the DOM.

Considering that this second function will only be necessary within this scenario, can I do that without having to declare the function explicitly?

Here's a demo:

More clearly, the idea is to dispense the need to declare the "close ()" function and set this functionality within the "show ()" function using only vanilla JS.

```js
function show() {
 var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute("id", "myDiv");
  div.innerHTML = "Hello World ";
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = "CLOSE";
  button.setAttribute("onclick","close();");
  div.appendChild(button);
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

function close() {
  //code to remove element
}
```

```css
#myDiv {
  background:yellow;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-top:10px;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="show();">
  Show
</button>
```

JSFIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/do4yq2w9/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign `onclick` of the button with a new function like below:

```js
function show() {
 var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute("id", "myDiv");
  div.innerHTML = "Hello World ";
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = "CLOSE";
  button.onclick = function() {
   document.getElementById('myDiv').remove();
  }
  div.appendChild(button);
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
#myDiv {
  background:yellow;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-top:10px;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="show();">
  Show
</button>
```